facebook pixel - content_id for multilingual page
I can not find this anywhere on FB support pages - I have multilingual store with same product translated in different languages (mystore.com/myproduct, mystore.com/de/myproduct etc..). When sending information using pixel - do I have to send same content_id for both translations (using SKU for example) or do I send different content_id (since it is different content basically)? Thannk you for any help.
